# Can i pass reference to first arg in bindParam?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this function.

```
function SelectSql($sqlarray){

    try {
        //build the query
        $where="";

        //build the where query
        if(!empty($sqlarray["where_cols"]))  
            $where.="WHERE " .$sqlarray["where_cols"];

        $sql="SELECT " . $sqlarray["prefix_from"] . " FROM " . $sqlarray["tables"] . " $where";
        echo $sql;

        $conn=Connect(); //connect

        $command = $conn->prepare($sql); //run the query

        foreach($sqlarray["prms"] as $prm_name=>$prm_value)   //build the prms
            $command->bindParam(":$prm_name",$prm_value);

        $command->execute(); //exec the query 
        $results=$command->fetchAll();

        if ($command->rowCount() > 0)  //check if there is a results
            return $results; //ret results
        else
            return false; //ret null
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

which intend to build the query.

now the `sample` function below call to the `SelectSql` above.

```
function sample(){
    $sql["tables"]="USERS";
    $sql["prefix_from"]="*";
    $sql["where_cols"]="username=:uname and showmail=:showmail";
    $sql["prms"]=array("uname"=>"eli","showmail"=>1);
    $result=SelectSql($sql);
    if($result==false) // no results
        echo "no";      
}
```

This is the table:

```
+----------+----------+
| username | showmail |
+----------+----------+
| eli      |        1 |
+----------+----------+
```

Why i get zero results ?

Thanks.

Comment: Posting a little more of your code might help elucidate where the bug is...

Comment: Did you do a `echo $prm_name`? What was it and what did you expect?..

Comment: i change the question and add the code.

Comment: Use `errorInfo` function to check query errors.

Comment: And consider `For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement.`

Comment: there is no error. and if i write it like this `$p1="uname";$v1="eli";$p2="showmail";$v2=1;    
    $command->bindParam(":$p1",$v1);
    $command->bindParam(":$p2",$v2);` it works. why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is in using `bindParam`.

As described in the manual:

> Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.

And as you use `bindParam` in a loop, at the moment of calling `execute` all your placeholders are binded to value of `$prm_value`, which is in the end of loop equals to last array item. i.e. 1 (value of `showemail`).

So, literally you query is

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE username = 1 and showmail = 1
```

Sure, not what you expect.

So, you should use `bindValue` in this case.